# Requests-html: searching for the xpath of an element returns an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape data from this website: [myworkdayjobs link](https://nvidia.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/NVIDIAExternalCareerSite?locations=91336993fab910af6d6f80c09504c167&jobFamilyGroup=0c40f6bd1d8f10ae43ffaefd46dc7e78)

The data I want to collect are the job advertisemnts and their respective data.
Currently there are 7 jobs active.

On the inspect page I can see the 7 wanted elements all having the same:
li class="css-1q2dra3"

But the page.html.xpath() always returns me an empty list.

The steps I've taken are:

```
session = HTMLSession()
url = (
    'https://nvidia.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/NVIDIAExternalCareerSite'
    '?locations=91336993fab910af6d6f80c09504c167'
    '&jobFamilyGroup=0c40f6bd1d8f10ae43ffaefd46dc7e78'
    )
page = session.get(url)
page.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1)
cards = page.html.xpath("the_xpath_here")
print(cards)
```

I've also tried multiple other xpaths including the xpath I get when I copy the xpath path from rightclicking the element on the inspect page:

```
//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/div[2]/section/ul/li[1]/div[1]
/html/body/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/section/ul/li[1]/div[1]
//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/div[2]/section/ul/li[1]
```

Now, the only time I get results for a li element is when I

```
cards = page.html.xpath('//li')
```

Which returns me the li elements at the bottom of the page. But it fully ignores the elements that I want...

I'm not an expert on webscraping or so, but I have made it work with an other careers page before. What am I missing? Why can't I access those elements?

=========================================================
Additional information:
The problem that I experience seems to happen after the section element.

When I

```
cards = page.html.xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/div[2]/section/*')
print(cards)

[<Element 'p' data-automation-id='jobFoundText' class=('css-12psxof',)>, <Element 'div' data-automation-id='jobJumpToDetailsContainer' class=('css-14l0ax5',)>, <Element 'div' class=('css-19kzrtu',)>]
```

Why isn't there no ul element in the list? It's clearly there in the inspect window.

=========================================================
**Answer**
(Because the answer is in the accepted solution comment)

The page had aparently not fully loaded by the time of the assignement of cards and thus the ul was not there yet.

Adding one more second on the renderer sleep did the trick (sleep=2).

```
session = HTMLSession()
url = (
    'https://nvidia.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/NVIDIAExternalCareerSite'
    '?locations=91336993fab910af6d6f80c09504c167'
    '&jobFamilyGroup=0c40f6bd1d8f10ae43ffaefd46dc7e78'
    )
page = session.get(url)
page.html.render(sleep=2, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1)
cards = page.html.xpath("the_xpath_here")
print(cards)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want li elements but your 3 variants of xpath point to div or single li. Try out specific xpath you need `'//li[@class="css-1q2dra3"]'`

Comment: I've already tried this and it still returns an empty list. I've metioned that I've tried the page.html.xpath('//li'). To get all the li elements of the page, but it only returns the li elements at the bottom of the page and fully ignores the ones that I need, like if they were not there...

Comment: could you make sure they are not inside iframe element?

Comment: also you may need to add delay before getting elements, as page may be not loaded yet at the moment script tries to reach it

Comment: Yeah, the sleep fixed it!

Comment: I'd recommend you to use Selenium library for scraping as far as it provides a lot of functionality, for example for this case, WebDriveWait methods to check availability of elements, so you won't hardcode delay but wait for desired element to be available

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use their Ajax API to get the Json data about the jobs. For example:

```py
import requests

api_url = (
    "https://nvidia.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/wday/cxs/nvidia/NVIDIAExternalCareerSite/jobs"
)

payload = {
    "appliedFacets": {
        "jobFamilyGroup": ["0c40f6bd1d8f10ae43ffaefd46dc7e78"],
        "locations": ["91336993fab910af6d6f80c09504c167"],
    },
    "limit": 20,
    "offset": 0,
    "searchText": "",
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "total": 7,
    "jobPostings": [
        {
            "title": "Senior CPU Compiler Engineer",
            "externalPath": "/job/UK-Remote/Senior-CPU-Compiler-Engineer_JR1954638",
            "locationsText": "7 Locations",
            "postedOn": "Posted 18 Days Ago",
            "bulletFields": ["JR1954638"],
        },
        {
            "title": "CPU Compiler Engineer",
            "externalPath": "/job/UK-Remote/CPU-Compiler-Engineer_JR1954640-1",
            "locationsText": "7 Locations",
            "postedOn": "Posted 26 Days Ago",
            "bulletFields": ["JR1954640"],
        },

...and so on.
```

Comment: Yes, I see. This gives me the wanted data, but isn't there a way to do it with requests-html instead of requests? Or maybe why is requests-html unable to find that data? I've noticed that when I try the xpath, I can get up to the section element, but it will return an empty list if I look for the elements inside section...